# How to get Subsidiary id using RESTlet in Netsuite?

Tags: php, netsuite

Test_Sub is a subsidiary which is set to Acccountant Role which is assigned to one user to whom RESTlet file was uploaded. I want assigned subsidiary id for the user from the RESTlet script.

i already got the following details :

```
    result['Name']         = nlapiGetContext().getName();
    result['Email']        = nlapiGetContext().getEmail();
    result['UserId']       = nlapiGetContext().getUser();
    result['RoleId']       = nlapiGetContext().getRole();
    result['RoleCenter']   = nlapiGetContext().getRoleCenter();
    result['SubsidiaryId'] = nlapiGetContext().getSubsidiary() ;
```

i tried to get subsidiary id by the above way. Even though i set different subsidiary for the role, i always got the result as 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nlapiGetContext().getSubsidiary()` will always return the subsidiary on the employee record of the user in the context of whom the RESTlet is invoked, and NOT the subsidiaries set on role of the RESTlet user.

Comment: Ok, Thanks Prasun, Are there any possibilities to get the subsidiaries set on role? Because all records are changed like lead, customer, contact, and so on by changing subsidiary in the role.

Comment: unfortunately, role is not scriptable. you can create a saved search on role, but, it appears that search isn't available via `nlapiLoadSearch()`